# How to Check if dependencies in Fiware Cygnus are in cygnus.jar

Tags: fiware-cygnus

Concerning the Fiware Cygnus installation. 
At the end of the installation process there is a list with required dependencies, [Link](http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cygnus-common/installation_and_administration_guide/install_from_sources/index.html). It is neccesarry to check if those dependencies are included in the cygnus.jar file.

How can I check if those packages are installed ? 
I know that I can display the content of a jar file with

```
jar tf cygnus-common-1.2.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

But I need to know if all of them are installed.

```
mockito-all
junit
flume-ng-node
httpclient
httpcore
libthrift
gson
json-simple
log4j
mysql-connector-java
postgresql
hadoop-core
hive-exec
hive-jdbc
mongodb-driver
kafka-clients
zkclient
kafka_2.11
aws-java-sdk-dynamodb
```

I am sure there is an easy way to check it. Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

If you have built Cygnus jar with dependencies, nothing has to be checked nor installed, since everything will be within the fat Cygnus jar. This is explained in the [documentation](http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cygnus-ngsi/installation_and_administration_guide/install_from_sources/index.html):

> cygnus-ngsi can be built as a fat Java jar file containing all third-party dependencies (recommended):
>
> $ cd cygnus-ngsi 
>   $ APACHE_MAVEN_HOME/bin/mvn clean compile exec:exec assembly:single 
>   $ cp target/cygnus-ngsi--jar-with-dependencies.jar 
>   APACHE_FLUME_HOME/plugins.d/cygnus/lib
>
> Or as a thin Java jar file:
>
> $ cd cygnus-ngsi
>   $ APACHE_MAVEN_HOME/bin/mvn exec:exec package 
>   $ cp target/cygnus-.jar APACHE_FLUME_HOME/plugins.d/cygnus/lib